# phantomjs click works on one link but not another in the same page

Tags: javascript, dom, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape a page with phantomjs. A list has to be filtered with options, so some clicking is involved.

Here's my code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };



page.open('http://jobs.bdjobs.com/jobsearch.asp?fcatId=1&icatId=', function () {

var coords = page.evaluate(function () {


var firstlink = document.querySelectorAll('a.dropdown-toggle')[0];


return {x: firstlink.offsetLeft, y: firstlink.offsetTop};


});


page.sendEvent('click', coords.x + 1, coords.y + 1);



page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {console.log(msg);}

page.render('bdjobs.png');


phantom.exit();


});
```

The output looks like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqPZI.png)

Even though the Keywords menu should have been toggled, it is not.

I'm sure that the code is working because when I click links at the top of the page, I can see in the screenshot that they have been clicked.

Here's the [page link](http://jobs.bdjobs.com/jobsearch.asp?fcatId=1&icatId=)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem#1 Using offsetLeft & offsetTop to determine the position for the click - these properties describe the position of the item relative to it's parent, not the viewport.

Problem#2 Not waiting long enough for the click event to fire before invoking page.render

Try this -

```
var page = require('webpage').create()

page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 }

page.open('http://jobs.bdjobs.com/jobsearch.asp?fcatId=1&icatId=', function() {
  var coords = page.evaluate(function() {
    var rect = document
      .querySelector('.dropdown-toggle i')
      .getBoundingClientRect()

    return { x: rect.left, y: rect.top }
  })

  page.sendEvent('click', coords.x, coords.y)

  page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
  }

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    page.render('bdjobs.png')

    phantom.exit()
  }, 3000)
})
```